# Use partitioning schema with user defined function

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, user-defined-functions

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am trying some partitioning stuff and have some question.

Here is a very simple example:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MyPartitionFunction (int)
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1,2)

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME MyPartitionScheme AS
PARTITION MyPartitionFunction ALL TO ([PRIMARY])

CREATE FUNCTION CalcPartitionValue (@value int) RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
BEGIN
   if @value % 2 = 0 return 1
   return 2
END

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(ID INT NOT NULL)
ON MyPartitionScheme (dbo.CalcPartitionValue(ID));
```

I want to use the user defined function as input for the partitioning function. Is there any way to get this working?

I know that it is possible to create a calculated column with the user defined function. But a schema update on a table with over 300 million rows will not be that fast. Thats why i am asking if it is possible to use the user defined function directly.

Answer (score 1):

try Persisted computed columns and use function as column formula. 
In function definition use "With Schemabinding" option and it will all work fine.